# How to select perticular class in jquery from a dynamic table

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to create a system to put sequence number of lessons, and i tried to make it unique as u can see that i take a variable $i but no luck . i am new in jquery. dont know how to use (this) in this situation. i am going to use ajax to save the data.

```
<?php
        $chapter_id = $_GET['id'];
        $lesson = mysqli_query($conn_course, "SELECT * FROM `lesson_list` WHERE `chapter_id` = '$chapter_id' order by `sequence` asc");
        $i=0;
        while ($info1 = mysqli_fetch_array($lesson)) {
            $lesson_id = $info1['lesson_id'];
            $lesson_info = mysqli_query($conn_course, "SELECT * FROM `lesson` WHERE `lesson_id` = '$lesson_id'");
            $info = mysqli_fetch_array($lesson_info);
            $i++;
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td>
                 <form>
                    <input type="hidden" class="lesson_id<?=$i?>" value="<?=$lesson_id?>">
                    <input type="hidden" class="sno" value="<?=$i?>">
                    <input type="hidden" id="chapter_id" value="<?=$chapter_id?>">
                    <input class="form-control sequence_no" style="width:27%;" type="number"  value="<?= $info1['sequence'] ?>">
                 </form>
        
          </td>
      <td>
        <a href="index.php?p=lesson-page&id=<?= $info['lesson_id'] ?>">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm">
              <?= $info['lesson_name'] ?>
    </button>
    </a>
      </td>
      <td>
    
    
                <?= strtoupper($info['code']) ?>
    
        </td>
        <td>
        <?php if($info['video_url'] == 0){}else{ ?>
            <a href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/<?= $info['video_url'] ?>" target="blank"><button type="button"
                    class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm">Play Video</button></a>
                    <?php } ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <form class="" action="../edit/delete.php" method="get" style="float:left; margin-right:5px;">
            <input type="hidden" name="chapter_id" value="<?=$_GET['id']?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="lesson_id" value="<?=$lesson_id?>">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm" name="delete_lesson" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete it')" value="Delete">
          </form>
          <a href="index.php?p=lesson-create&task=edit&id=<?= $info['lesson_id'] ?>&page=chapter-page&chapter_id=<?=$chapter_id?>">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm">Edit
              </button>
          </a>
        </td>
    
    
    </tr>
    
    <?php } ?>
```

myjquery is

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.sequence_no').on("change", function () {
        var sequence_no = $('.sequence_no').val();
        var s_no = $('.sno').val();
        var chapter_id = $('#chapter_id').val();

        var lesson_id = $('.lesson_id' + s_no).val();

        alert(s_no);
    })

})
```

alert is showing only the first table row s_no. how to select the lesson id of particular tr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply get closest `tr` using `$(this).closest("tr")` and then use `.find` to get required classes values .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.sequence_no').on("change", function() {
  var selector = $(this).closest("tr")
  var sequence_no = $(this).val();
  var s_no = selector.find('.sno').val();
  var chapter_id = selector.find('.chapter_id').val();
  var lesson_id = selector.find('input[class*=lesson_id]').val();
  console.log(s_no, lesson_id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form>
        <!--added class-->
        <input type="hidden" class="lesson_id<?=$i?>" value="22">
        <input type="hidden" class="sno" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" class="chapter_id" value="1">
        <input class="form-control sequence_no" style="width:27%;" type="number" value="2">
      </form>

    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="index.php?p=lesson-page&id=<?= $info['lesson_id'] ?>">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm">
             Smething
    </button>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      Abc
    </td>

    <td>
      <form class="" action="../edit/delete.php" method="get" style="float:left; margin-right:5px;">
        <input type="hidden" name="chapter_id" value="<?=$_GET['id']?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="lesson_id" value="1">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm" name="delete_lesson" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete it')" value="Delete">
      </form>
      <a href="index.php?p=lesson-create&task=edit&id=<?= $info['lesson_id'] ?>&page=chapter-page&chapter_id=<?=$chapter_id?>">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm">Edit
              </button>
      </a>
    </td>


  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form>
        <input type="hidden" class="lesson_id<?=$i?>" value="26">
        <input type="hidden" class="sno" value="2">
        <input type="hidden" class="chapter_id" value="2">
        <input class="form-control sequence_no" style="width:27%;" type="number" value="2">
      </form>

    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="index.php?p=lesson-page&id=<?= $info['lesson_id'] ?>">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm">
            Smething
    </button>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      Abc2
    </td>

    <td>
      <form class="" action="../edit/delete.php" method="get" style="float:left; margin-right:5px;">
        <input type="hidden" name="chapter_id" value="<?=$_GET['id']?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="lesson_id" value="2">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm" name="delete_lesson" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete it')" value="Delete">
      </form>
      <a href="index.php?p=lesson-create&task=edit&id=<?= $info['lesson_id'] ?>&page=chapter-page&chapter_id=<?=$chapter_id?>">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm">Edit
              </button>
      </a>
    </td>


  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks @swati it works, need to learn alot about javascript.